# Adding elements to an array using key/value in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I know I can add elemnts to an array like this:

```
$arr = array("foo" => "bar", 12 => true);
```

Now, how can I do that in a foreach using dynamic values? I have this code:

```
foreach ($values as $value) {

    $imagePath = $value->getImagePath();
    $dependsOn = $value->getDependsOn();
    $dependsOn = explode(':', $dependsOn);
    $dependsOnOptionValueTitle = trim($dependsOn[1]);

    array_push($paths, $dependsOnOptionValueTitle => $imagePath); // not working
}
```

How can I add key/value pairs to my `$paths` array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see, this is what you're trying to do:

```
$paths[$dependsOnOptionValueTitle] = $imagePath;
```

Comment if I'm wrong and I'll try to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
array_push($paths, $dependsOnOptionValueTitle => $imagePath); // not working
```

you should be able to use

```
$paths[$dependsOnOptionValueTitle] = $imagePath;
```